# SVMWithSGD in Spark documentation example not working

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running Spark 1.1.0 with PySpark.

When I run the example taken straight from the documentation:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.classification import SVMWithSGD
import array

data = [
    LabeledPoint(0.0, [0.0]),
    LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0]),
    LabeledPoint(1.0, [2.0]),
    LabeledPoint(1.0, [3.0])
]

svm = SVMWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(data))
svm.predict(array([1.0])) > 0
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-68bcda022b28> in <module>()
     12 
     13 svm = SVMWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(data))
---> 14 svm.predict(array([1.0])) > 0

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was importing the **wrong array package**.

```
import array
```

instead of

```
from numpy import array
```